# Why MediaPlayer.getCurrentPoition() always return the same value in Android?

Tags: android, media

Im working with a music streaming app. After I get the song from Spotify I use MediaPlayer to handle the controls.

Here is part of the code I'm working on:

```
public class LocalPlayerController implements MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener, SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {

//...
    private LocalPlayerController(){
        if(player==null) player = new MediaPlayer();
    }

    //...

    public void play(String path,int songIndex){
        if(player!=null) player.stop();
        player = new MediaPlayer();
        player.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        currentSongIndex = songIndex;
        try {
            player.reset();
            player.setDataSource(path);

            player.prepare();
            player.start();

        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    //...

    @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            if (fromUser){
            player.seekTo(player.getCurrentPosition()+progress*1000);
        }
    }

//...
}
```

So far it reproduces well the music I toss at it, but when I call a MediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() it returns the same value in every time, I think its supposed to update along with the time it has been since the music started playing. I need that changing value to be able to call MediaPlayer.seekTo().

What's happening? Why the progress won't update?

Comment: Ehm wouldn't you want to do this to seek it according to the progressbar: `player.seekTo(mediaPlayer.getDuration() * progress / 100);` while progress max is 100

Comment: I set the Max length of the progress bar according to the object song tat i get.

Comment: then it's just `player.seekTo(progress);` . you dont need the current position since they're synchronized

Comment: That is the main approach. But whenever i call MediaPlayer.seekTo(progress) an error says: android media player pause called in state 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

I call player.start() inside the onPreparedListener implementation instead of calling it explicitly